# ssh from Jenkins instance gives no error message

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm calling these commands in JenkinsFile. In Jenkins Execution, the process hangs on `ssh -tt centos@xxx.ubuntu.net` and doesn't move.

ssh-key has been added to Jenkins credential and I'm not sure if it's not responding or having a problem with proxy.

```
ssh -tt centos@xxx.ubuntu.net <<< STUCK HERE
echo "got in to the server"
sudo su -
sudo su muser
org=new
echo "success"
// Git pull
exit
exit
exit
```

What should I try to solve this? It doesn't show any error message on Jenkins side so it's embarrassing.

Comment: I added -tt to avoid `“Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.”` error.

Comment: Hi, @hellofanengineer questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score -1):

Something you can try to solve this is to debug your ssh session.  Do this by hand (not in your script) just to check:

```
ssh -vvv centos@xxx.ubuntu.net
```

This will allow you to potentially spot the problem and perhaps give some direction on how to troubleshoot further.  Try that out and see if anything pops out at you.